# Every time that Cron Jobs are running they FREEZE my User Interface in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5, cron

In an application, we run certain cronjobs every night. Our backend is based on PHP - Laravel and the front is Angular and PHP - Laravel.

During this time that these cronjobs are running in the back, the User Interface is frozen and you can't do anything. Dead. We have no errors, no brakes, nothing. Is anyone had the same issue before?

Comment: Any error messages anywhere in the system? Memory issues?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's the first time we wish to have some error messages ;(

Comment: The server is running on very low resources. No memory, no CPU loads. We have some network picks during the cronjobs.